# What is the structure of DELETE request in Google Sheets APIv4

Tags: postman, google-sheets-api

Is the delete request still usable in `sheets API v4`? If yes, can someone please give me an example that will result in `200` and `OK`?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `What is the structure of DELETE request in Google Sheets APIv4`, What is `the structure of DELETE request` in Sheets API v4?

Comment: I understand, no need to apologize, thank you for your suggestion. I'm still new to using stack overflow so any suggestions are really needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. what I would like to say is that is there any way I can use DELETE request in Postman in Google sheets API. From my research, there's no DELETE request anymore in google sheets apiv4. They have change it to POST method. For example: In deleting a sheet in APIv3 you can use DELETE request <URL>, but in APIv4 it is now POST <URL:batchupdate> with request body. More on this in https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#v4-api_8